# TracStatsPlugin there is no code stats

Tags: trac

Sorry for my language. I have problem with TracStatsPlugin. I added in trac.ini following lines:

```
[components]
tracstats.* = enabled

[stats]
root = /home/tracDirectory
```

Now I have stats for wiki and tickets but no for code. What can be wrong ? I add that I have configured svn repository and I can browse source using trac. 
A salvation can be other stats plugin to trac, but I can't find nothing good in google.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using?  If you are using Internet Explorer, try using Firefox or Chrome and see if the problem persists.  I am using the TracStats plugin and I see similar problems.  The problems are only seen in Internet Explorer, though.  After poking around with the debugger, it looks like there's an IE-specific bug in one of the Javascript libraries that the plugin uses.

Answer (score 0):

Question was aced long time ago, but google show it in first places so I put what I found here.

Once there was ticket on TracStatsPlugin Github about issue: https://github.com/mrjbq7/tracstats/issues/25 so some workarounds can be found in it comments.